# How to have one master To Do List from To Do lists on different pages?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, to-do

Is it possible to display to do lists from other pages on a single page for easy and quick access of all tasks?

Answer (score 6):

1. On the Home tab, click the *Find Tags* button, and a pane will open on the right side listing all of your Tags.
2. At the bottom of the pane, click *Create Summary Page*.

It will list **all** the tags, but it's easy to delete the ones that are not To-do items. And if you select or hover over an item, it displays a "OneNote" [image: N] icon that you can click on to navigate to the page the original item is on. Quick and easy enough for you?

Comment: This is *almost* really useful, but once the summary page is created it doesn't reflect any changes made to the lists that it summarises. If I check off an item on one of the linked to-do lists, the item on the summary page is not checked, and if I add items to the linked lists they don't appear on the summary page. It seems to essentially be a snapshot of the linked lists at the time the summary was created, which is only of very limited use.